Alternative proofs for $\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq1+2\sum_{i=1}^na_i$
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$ with $a_1,\,...,\,a_n\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\leq1$
To show is $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq1+2\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$
A similar question has already been asked, see: Use induction to prove $\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq1+2\sum_{i=1}^na_i$
A proof without induction is as follows:
For simplicity, we denote $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ as $S$
AM–GM inequality yields $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq\left(1+\frac{S}{n}\right)^n$$
Furthermore is $\left(1+\frac{S}{n}\right)^n\leq e^S$, so $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq e^S$$
Lastly, $$e^S\leq 1+2S$$ holds for $0\leq S\leq1$ which completes the proof.
Note, that this method immediately yields a stronger statement $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq1+(e-1)\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$ because $e^S\leq 1+(e-1)S$ for $0\leq S\leq1$
Now, a proof with induction. We first prove something more abstract...
Let $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and convex, and let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq x\leq1$
Furthermore, let $1+x\leq f(x)$ and $f(x)\leq f'(x)$
To show is $$\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+a_i\right)\leq f\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)$$
Base case holds because of $1+x\leq f(x)$ $$\prod_{i=1}^1\left(1+a_i\right)=1+a_1\leq f(a_1)=f\left(\sum_{i=1}^1a_i\right)$$
Induction step:
Since $f$ is differentiable and convex, we have for $h\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with $x+h\leq1$ $$f'(x)\leq\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Because of $f(x)\leq f'(x)$ we get $$f(x)\leq\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\Longleftrightarrow f(x)(1+h)\leq f(x+h)$$
Overall $$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1+a_i)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\right)\left(1+a_{n+1}\right)\leq f\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)\left(1+a_{n+1}\right)\leq f\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)+a_{n+1}\right)=f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i\right)$$
which completes the proof.
Now, to prove our initial statement $\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq1+2\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ we prove another, stronger statement instead $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\leq1+\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2$$
$f(x):=1+x+x^2$ is differentiable and convex. Furthermore:
$$1+x\leq f(x)\Longleftrightarrow 1+x\leq 1+x+x^2 \Longleftrightarrow 0\leq x^2$$
$$f(x)\leq f'(x)\Longleftrightarrow 1+x+x^2\leq 1+2x \Longleftrightarrow x(x-1)\leq 0$$
which completes the proof.
My questions:

I am interested in seeing more proofs - so, what can you come up with?
I am especially interested in proofs, which start "more abstract", like my second proof.

$e^x$, differentiability and convexity seem to be nice tools, when it comes to proving this statement, and I'm wondering, whether there are "more tools" ;)


